# ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyGObject'. It is a distutils installed project

Tags: python

I am updating PyGObject and give an error.

How should I update PyGObject

.....

Environment：

```
macOS Big Sur 11.5.2

python --version
Python 3.9.7

pip --version
pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

my operation.

ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyGObject'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

```
pip install --upgrade PyGObject



DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: PyGObject in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.40.1)
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached PyGObject-3.42.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pycairo>=1.16.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from PyGObject) (1.20.1)
Installing collected packages: PyGObject
  Attempting uninstall: PyGObject
    Found existing installation: PyGObject 3.40.1
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyGObject'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Answer (score 0):

Pip is unsure on the package dependencies to clean up in the upgrade. You can force the upgrade by telling it to ignore what is already installed.

```
pip install PyGObject --ignore-installed
```

Comment: Does PyGObject 3.40.1 still exist? According to the operation, I updated to PyGObject-3.42.0

Comment: Why do you need to upgrade pygobject? You should consider using a virtualenv. Normally system python environment should not be touched.

Comment: could you add some context to the question?